# build and install git from source on macOS Sonama 14.x: "ld: multiple errors: archive member '/' not a mach-o file"

Tags: git, macos

I'm trying to build git from source (`https://github.com/git/git.git`) by using bash as default shell in git alias, so I don't have to identify `echo -e` or `echo` for output.

However, I've encounter the issue when execute `make all`:

```bash
...
    LINK t/helper/test-tool
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-liconv', 'libgit.a'
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-liconv', 'libgit.a'
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-liconv', 'libgit.a'
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-liconv', 'libgit.a'
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-liconv', 'libgit.a'
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-liconv', 'libgit.a'
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-liconv', 'libgit.a'
ld: multiple errors: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/xdiff/lib.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/reftable/libreftable.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/libgit.a'
ld: multiple errors: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/xdiff/lib.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/reftable/libreftable.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/libgit.a'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [git-daemon] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
ld: multiple errors: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/libgit.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/xdiff/lib.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/reftable/libreftable.a'
make: *** [git-http-backend] Error 1
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ld: multiple errors: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/libgit.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/reftable/libreftable.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/xdiff/lib.a'
make: *** [git-imap-send] Error 1
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ld: multiple errors: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/libgit.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/xdiff/lib.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/reftable/libreftable.a'
ld: multiple errors: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/xdiff/lib.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/libgit.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/reftable/libreftable.a'
make: *** [git-sh-i18n--envsubst] Error 1
ld: multiple errors: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/libgit.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/xdiff/lib.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/reftable/libreftable.a'
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-liconv', 'libgit.a', 'reftable/libreftable.a', 'xdiff/lib.a'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-liconv', 'libgit.a'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [git-http-push] Error 1
make: *** [git-remote-http] Error 1
make: *** [git-http-fetch] Error 1
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-liconv', 'libgit.a'
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-liconv', 'libgit.a'
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-liconv', 'libgit.a', 'reftable/libreftable.a', 'xdiff/lib.a'
ld: multiple errors: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/reftable/libreftable_test.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/reftable/libreftable.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/xdiff/lib.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/libgit.a'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [t/helper/test-fake-ssh] Error 1
ld: multiple errors: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/libgit.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/xdiff/lib.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/reftable/libreftable.a'
ld: multiple errors: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/reftable/libreftable.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/xdiff/lib.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/libgit.a'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ld: multiple errors: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/libgit.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/xdiff/lib.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/reftable/libreftable.a'
make: *** [git] Error 1
make: *** [scalar] Error 1
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [git-shell] Error 1
ld: multiple errors: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/libgit.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/reftable/libreftable.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/xdiff/lib.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/marslo/tools/git/reftable/libreftable_test.a'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [t/helper/test-tool] Error 1
```

here are details:

- full steps:

  ```bash
  $ mkdir -p $HOME/tools/git
  $ git clone https://github.com/git/git.git $HOME/tools/git
  $ cd $HOME/tools/git

  # status
  $ git show -s HEAD
  commit 564d0252ca632e0264ed670534a51d18a689ef5d (HEAD -> master, tag: v2.43.0, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
  Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
  Date:   Mon Nov 20 08:47:38 2023 +0900

      Git 2.43

      Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>

  # build
  $ make configure
  $ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-shell=/usr/local/bin/bash
  $ make -j all
  ```
- logs:

  - [full logs can can be found in gist](https://gist.github.com/marslo/c6a3cbce17f4d53a3d223d1313a2d302#file-z_1_configure-log-md)
  - [full logs can be found in gist](https://gist.github.com/marslo/c6a3cbce17f4d53a3d223d1313a2d302#file-z_2_make-log-md)
- environment

  ```bash
  $ sw_vers
  ProductName:          macOS
  ProductVersion:       14.1.2
  BuildVersion:         23B92

  $ brew install gcc autoconf automake openssl@3 expat gettext zlib libtool libiconv ncurses
  $ brew install asciidoc xmlto docbook2x docbook-xsl hunspell
  $ ln -sf /usr/local/bin/docbook2texi /usr/local/bin/docbook2x-texi
  $ brew install gnu-getopt libao

  $ echo $CFLAGS
  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include
  $ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  /usr/local/opt/curl/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/11.1:/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/python@3.11/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libressl/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c@71.1/71.1/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/expat/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/pkgconfig
  $ echo $CPPFLAGS
  -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/usr/local/opt/openldap/include -I/usr/local/opt/curl/include -I/usr/local/opt/binutils/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/node/21.1.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/libressl/include -I/usr/local/opt/expat/include -I/usr/local/opt/ncurses/include -I/usr/local/opt/libiconv/include -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include -I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c@71.1/71.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include
  $ echo $LDFLAGS
  -L/usr/local/opt/openldap/lib -L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/binutils/lib -L/usr/local/opt/python@3.11/lib -L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib -L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/node/21.1.0/libexec/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libressl/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c@71.1/71.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/expat/lib -L/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/c++ -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/c++

  $ gcc --version
  Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin23.1.0
  Thread model: posix
  InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

  $ g++ --version
  Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin23.1.0
  Thread model: posix
  InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

  $ clang --version
  Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin23.1.0
  Thread model: posix
  InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

  $ gettext --version
  gettext (GNU gettext-runtime) 0.22.4
  Copyright (C) 1995-2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
  This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
  There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
  Written by Ulrich Drepper.

  $ autoconf --version
  autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.71
  Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  License GPLv3+/Autoconf: GNU GPL version 3 or later
  <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>, <https://gnu.org/licenses/exceptions.html>
  This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
  There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

  Written by David J. MacKenzie and Akim Demaille.
  ```

Comment: Where did the offending libraries come from? If you compiled them yourself, how did you do that?

Comment: @tripleee, the `liconv` is coming from `$ brew install libiconv`, and `libgit.a` should be built from `$ make all`

Comment: And how does `/Users/marslo/tools/git/`relate to the project you are currently building? Is this where you have checked out this project, or an earlier build?

Comment: @tripleee, the `$HOME/tools/git` is from `$ git clone https://github.com/git/git.git $HOME/tools/git`, need to create `$HOME/tools/git` in advance.

Comment: @tripleee, so pretty much the steps are:
```$ mkdir -p $HOME/tools/git; 
$ git clone https://github.com/git/git.git $HOME/tools/git;
$ make configure; 
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-shell=/usr/local/bin/bash; 
$ make -j all; 
```

Comment: Probably [edit] your question to make it self-contained. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre]. You are more likely to get help if you can demonstrate that you have checked the obvious explanations.

Comment: @tripleee done.

Comment: It looks like you install GCC, but then do not take extra steps to use it to build. So the build uses the system `gcc` alias which is in fact Clang (as we see in the build log). Is this what you want? by the way you do not need automake to build Git.

Comment: @philb, the `make confiugre` step is getting from [Git - Install Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git), and actually I've tried to using `export CC=clang; export CXX=clang++` instead of `GCC/CC` and also failed with same issues, [full logs can be found in gist as well](https://gist.github.com/marslo/c6a3cbce17f4d53a3d223d1313a2d302?permalink_comment_id=4786628#gistcomment-4786628)

Answer (score 0):

I get clue from [Clang archive or linking issue. Xcode 15.0.1](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/741149), looks like the issue comes from xCode15.

I will keep following up the issue and any update or solution will posted.